# How can I determine the status of a job?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a Stored procedure which schedules a job. This Job takes a lot of time to get completed (approx 30 to 40 min). I need to get to know the status of this Job.
Below details would help me

1) How to see the list of all jobs that have got scheduled for a future time and are yet to start

2) How to see the the list of jobs running and the time span from when they are running

3) How to see if the job has completed successfully or has stoped in between because of any error.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You could try using the system stored procedure sp_help_job. This returns information on the job, its steps, schedules and servers. For example

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_help_job @Job_name = 'Your Job Name'
```

[SQL Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186722(SQL.90).aspx) should contain lots of information about the records it returns.

For returning information on multiple jobs, you could try querying the following system tables which hold the various bits of information on the job

- msdb.dbo.SysJobActivity (thanks to @kenny-evitt)
- msdb.dbo.SysJobs
- msdb.dbo.SysJobSteps
- msdb.dbo.SysJobSchedules
- msdb.dbo.SysJobServers
- msdb.dbo.SysJobHistory

Their names are fairly self-explanatory (apart from SysJobServers which hold information on when the job last run and the outcome).

Again, information on the fields can be found at MSDN. For example, check out the page for [SysJobs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189817.aspx)

Comment: The table msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity is needed to actually determine whether a job is currently running. The table msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory is apparently only populated *after* a job (or a step?) finishes – and it's not populated at all for job started 'manually' (i.e. not from a job schedule).

Comment: How to know what was the actual starting Step?

Comment: This is a very general answer. The solution proposed by @efesar does work. Please consider mark it as answer [next](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18062236/3226105)

Answer (score 114):

I would like to point out that none of the T-SQL on this page will work precisely because none of them join to the **syssessions** table to get only the current session and therefore could include false positives.

See this for reference: [What does it mean to have jobs with a null stop date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13037668/what-does-it-mean-to-have-jobs-with-a-null-stop-date/13038752#13038752)

You can also validate this by analyzing the **sp_help_jobactivity** procedure in **msdb**.

I realize that this is an old message on SO, but I found this message only partially helpful because of the problem.

```
SELECT
    job.name, 
    job.job_id, 
    job.originating_server, 
    activity.run_requested_date, 
    DATEDIFF( SECOND, activity.run_requested_date, GETDATE() ) as Elapsed
FROM 
    msdb.dbo.sysjobs_view job
JOIN
    msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity activity
ON 
    job.job_id = activity.job_id
JOIN
    msdb.dbo.syssessions sess
ON
    sess.session_id = activity.session_id
JOIN
(
    SELECT
        MAX( agent_start_date ) AS max_agent_start_date
    FROM
        msdb.dbo.syssessions
) sess_max
ON
    sess.agent_start_date = sess_max.max_agent_start_date
WHERE 
    run_requested_date IS NOT NULL AND stop_execution_date IS NULL
```

Comment: This should really be the answer.  There's at least one other StackOverflow question about this (here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18445825/how-to-know-status-of-currently-running-jobs) where one of the commenters found that just finding sysjobactivity records where stop_execution_date is null will include records with run_requested_date from weeks ago that are obviously not still running.  I found the same thing myself and when I looked at the session_ids of the stuck records I found they were for previous sessions.  Running @efesar's query above excluded those historical records.

Comment: I agree.  This should definitely be the answer as it is succinct and tells you exactly what jobs are currently running and for how long.

Comment: this should ne answer +1

Comment: Agree. I am testing this solution in SQLServer 2016 with a job that ran several months before and the script checking the execution status not taking in account the agent_start_date so it always responded "the job is running".

Answer (score 30):

This is what I'm using to get the running jobs (principally so I can kill the ones which have probably hung):

```
SELECT
    job.Name, job.job_ID
    ,job.Originating_Server
    ,activity.run_requested_Date
    ,datediff(minute, activity.run_requested_Date, getdate()) AS Elapsed
FROM
    msdb.dbo.sysjobs_view job 
        INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity activity
        ON (job.job_id = activity.job_id)
WHERE
    run_Requested_date is not null 
    AND stop_execution_date is null
    AND job.name like 'Your Job Prefix%'
```

As Tim said, the MSDN / BOL documentation is reasonably good on the contents of the sysjobsX tables. Just remember they are tables in MSDB.

Comment: This method is preferred over the use of the stored procedure msdb.dbo.sp_help_job if this information is to be used programmatically (e.g. for writing T-SQL code that depends on whether a job is running).

Comment: It was surprisingly hard to find out the execution time of a currently running job. All scripts that I had found only included the execution time of the job's last run. This answer is my needle in a haystack.

Answer (score 16):

```
-- Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Standard Edition:
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 
          FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs J 
          JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity A 
              ON A.job_id=J.job_id 
          WHERE J.name=N'Your Job Name' 
          AND A.run_requested_date IS NOT NULL 
          AND A.stop_execution_date IS NULL
         )
    PRINT 'The job is running!'
ELSE
    PRINT 'The job is not running.'
```

Comment: Our sql server crashed so the stop_execution_date is NULL forever.  So this is not solution for me.

Answer (score 6):

I used the top-rated answer to create a simple SQL Function to check if a SQL Agent Job is already running:

```
-- ===================================================================================
-- Function: "IsJobAlreadyRunning"  |  Author: Geoff Griswald  |  Created: 2021-05-06
-- Description: Check if a SQL Agent Job is already Running - Return 1 if Yes, 0 if No
-- ===================================================================================
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.IsJobAlreadyRunning (@AgentJobName varchar(140))
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Result bit = 0
     IF EXISTS (SELECT job.name
                  FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs_view job
            INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity activity ON job.job_id = activity.job_id
            INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.syssessions sess ON sess.session_id = activity.session_id
            INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(agent_start_date) AS max_agent_start_date
                          FROM msdb.dbo.syssessions) sess_max ON sess.agent_start_date = sess_max.max_agent_start_date
                 WHERE run_requested_date IS NOT NULL 
                   AND stop_execution_date IS NULL
                   AND job.name = @AgentJobName)
   SET @Result = 1
RETURN @Result
END;
```

This is useful because I can call this function and check if the job I want to start is already running before I attempt to start it, without adding a lot of bloat to my code. for example:

```
DECLARE @JobName varchar(140) = 'MyAgentJobName'
     IF (SELECT dbo.IsJobAlreadyRunning(@JobName)) = 0
   EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @JobName
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT sj.name
  FROM msdb..sysjobactivity aj
  JOIN msdb..sysjobs sj
    on sj.job_id = aj.job_id
 WHERE aj.stop_execution_date  IS NULL     -- job hasn't stopped running
   AND aj.start_execution_date IS NOT NULL -- job is currently running
   AND sj.name = '<your Job Name>'
   AND NOT EXISTS( -- make sure this is the most recent run
                   select 1
                     from msdb..sysjobactivity new
                    where new.job_id = aj.job_id
                      and new.start_execution_date > aj.start_execution_date ) )
print 'running'
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer  and provide your code with some explanation

Comment: What's the extra explanation needed other than, this code does exactly what the user asked for...

Answer (score 4):

This will show last run status/time or if running, it shows current run time, step number/info, and SPID (if it has associated SPID). It also shows enabled/disabled and job user where it converts to NT SID format for unresolved user accounts.

```
CREATE TABLE #list_running_SQL_jobs
(
    job_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL
  , last_run_date INT NOT NULL
  , last_run_time INT NOT NULL
  , next_run_date INT NOT NULL
  , next_run_time INT NOT NULL
  , next_run_schedule_id INT NOT NULL
  , requested_to_run INT NOT NULL
  , request_source INT NOT NULL
  , request_source_id sysname NULL
  , running INT NOT NULL
  , current_step INT NOT NULL
  , current_retry_attempt INT NOT NULL
  , job_state INT NOT NULL
);

DECLARE @sqluser NVARCHAR(128)
      , @is_sysadmin INT;

SELECT @is_sysadmin = ISNULL(IS_SRVROLEMEMBER(N'sysadmin'), 0);

DECLARE read_sysjobs_for_running CURSOR FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT SUSER_SNAME(owner_sid)FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs;
OPEN read_sysjobs_for_running;
FETCH NEXT FROM read_sysjobs_for_running
INTO @sqluser;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #list_running_SQL_jobs
    EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_sqlagent_enum_jobs @is_sysadmin, @sqluser;
    FETCH NEXT FROM read_sysjobs_for_running
    INTO @sqluser;
END;

CLOSE read_sysjobs_for_running;
DEALLOCATE read_sysjobs_for_running;

SELECT j.name
     , 'Enbld' = CASE j.enabled
                     WHEN 0
                         THEN 'no'
                     ELSE 'YES'
                 END
     , '#Min' = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, a.start_execution_date, ISNULL(a.stop_execution_date, GETDATE()))
     , 'Status' = CASE
                      WHEN a.start_execution_date IS NOT NULL
                          AND a.stop_execution_date IS NULL
                          THEN 'Executing'
                      WHEN h.run_status = 0
                          THEN 'FAILED'
                      WHEN h.run_status = 2
                          THEN 'Retry'
                      WHEN h.run_status = 3
                          THEN 'Canceled'
                      WHEN h.run_status = 4
                          THEN 'InProg'
                      WHEN h.run_status = 1
                          THEN 'Success'
                      ELSE 'Idle'
                  END
     , r.current_step
     , spid = p.session_id
     , owner = ISNULL(SUSER_SNAME(j.owner_sid), 'S-' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(12), CONVERT(BIGINT, UNICODE(LEFT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(256), j.owner_sid), 1))) - CONVERT(BIGINT, 256) * CONVERT(BIGINT, UNICODE(LEFT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(256), j.owner_sid), 1)) / 256)) + '-' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(12), UNICODE(RIGHT(LEFT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(256), j.owner_sid), 4), 1)) / 256 + CONVERT(BIGINT, NULLIF(UNICODE(LEFT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(256), j.owner_sid), 1)) / 256, 0)) - CONVERT(BIGINT, UNICODE(LEFT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(256), j.owner_sid), 1)) / 256)) + ISNULL('-' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(12), CONVERT(BIGINT, UNICODE(RIGHT(LEFT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(256), j.owner_sid), 5), 1))) + CONVERT(BIGINT, UNICODE(RIGHT(LEFT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(256), j.owner_sid), 6), 1))) * CONVERT(BIGINT, 65536) + CONVERT(BIGINT, NULLIF(SIGN(LEN(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(256), j.owner_sid)) - 6), -1)) * 0), '') + ISNULL('-' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(12), CONVERT(BIGINT, UNICODE(RIGHT(LEFT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(256), j.owner_sid), 7), 1))) + CONVERT(BIGINT, UNICODE(RIGHT(LEFT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(256), j.owner_sid), 8), 1))) * CONVERT(BIGINT, 65536) + CONVERT(BIGINT, NULLIF(SIGN(LEN(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(256), j.owner_sid)) - 8), -1)) * 0), '') + ISNULL('-' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(12), CONVERT(BIGINT, UNICODE(RIGHT(LEFT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(256), j.owner_sid), 9), 1))) + CONVERT(BIGINT, UNICODE(RIGHT(LEFT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(256), j.owner_sid), 10), 1))) * CONVERT(BIGINT, 65536) + CONVERT(BIGINT, NULLIF(SIGN(LEN(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(256), j.owner_sid)) - 10), -1)) * 0), '') + ISNULL('-' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(12), CONVERT(BIGINT, UNICODE(RIGHT(LEFT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(256), j.owner_sid), 11), 1))) + CONVERT(BIGINT, UNICODE(RIGHT(LEFT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(256), j.owner_sid), 12), 1))) * CONVERT(BIGINT, 65536) + CONVERT(BIGINT, NULLIF(SIGN(LEN(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(256), j.owner_sid)) - 12), -1)) * 0), '') + ISNULL('-' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(12), CONVERT(BIGINT, UNICODE(RIGHT(LEFT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(256), j.owner_sid), 13), 1))) + CONVERT(BIGINT, UNICODE(RIGHT(LEFT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(256), j.owner_sid), 14), 1))) * CONVERT(BIGINT, 65536) + CONVERT(BIGINT, NULLIF(SIGN(LEN(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(256), j.owner_sid)) - 14), -1)) * 0), '')) --SHOW as NT SID when unresolved
     , a.start_execution_date
     , a.stop_execution_date
     , t.subsystem
     , t.step_name
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs j
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM #list_running_SQL_jobs) r
        ON j.job_id = r.job_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity a
        ON j.job_id = a.job_id
            AND a.start_execution_date IS NOT NULL
            --AND a.stop_execution_date IS NULL
            AND NOT EXISTS
            (
                SELECT *
                FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity at
                WHERE at.job_id = a.job_id
                    AND at.start_execution_date > a.start_execution_date
            )
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions p
        ON p.program_name LIKE 'SQLAgent%0x%'
            AND j.job_id = SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(p.program_name, CHARINDEX('0x', p.program_name) + 2, 32), 7, 2) + SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(p.program_name, CHARINDEX('0x', p.program_name) + 2, 32), 5, 2) + SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(p.program_name, CHARINDEX('0x', p.program_name) + 2, 32), 3, 2) + SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(p.program_name, CHARINDEX('0x', p.program_name) + 2, 32), 1, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(p.program_name, CHARINDEX('0x', p.program_name) + 2, 32), 11, 2) + SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(p.program_name, CHARINDEX('0x', p.program_name) + 2, 32), 9, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(p.program_name, CHARINDEX('0x', p.program_name) + 2, 32), 15, 2) + SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(p.program_name, CHARINDEX('0x', p.program_name) + 2, 32), 13, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(p.program_name, CHARINDEX('0x', p.program_name) + 2, 32), 17, 4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(p.program_name, CHARINDEX('0x', p.program_name) + 2, 32), 21, 12)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory h
        ON j.job_id = h.job_id
            AND h.instance_id = a.job_history_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps t
        ON t.job_id = j.job_id
            AND t.step_id = r.current_step
ORDER BY 1;

DROP TABLE #list_running_SQL_jobs;
```

Comment: This code is about 99% of what I'm looking for.  Think there is a way to add another column that shows the last run duration of a currently executing job?
I tried tying in the sysjobhistory.run_duration field but that won't pull back a value if the current status is "Executing".
Thanks for getting me this far.

Comment: thanks @johnMerager this is a great script

Answer (score 3):

we can query the msdb in many ways to get the details.

few are

```
select job.Name, job.job_ID, job.Originating_Server,activity.run_requested_Date,
datediff(minute, activity.run_requested_Date, getdate()) as Elapsed 
from msdb.dbo.sysjobs_view job 
inner join msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity activity on (job.job_id = activity.job_id) 
where run_Requested_date is not null 
and stop_execution_date is null 
and job.name like 'Your Job Prefix%'
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't specified how would you like to see these details.

For the first sight I would suggest to check [Server Management Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/info.aspx?na=22&p=1&SrcDisplayLang=en&SrcCategoryId=&SrcFamilyId=&u=%2fdownloads%2fdetails.aspx%3fFamilyID%3dc243a5ae-4bd1-4e3d-94b8-5a0f62bf7796%26DisplayLang%3den).

You can see the jobs and current statuses in the SQL Server Agent part, under Jobs. If you pick a job, the Property page shows a link to the Job History, where you can see the start and end time, if there any errors, which step caused the error, and so on.

You can specify alerts and notifications to email you or to page you when the job finished successfully or failed.

There is a Job Activity Monitor, but actually I never used it. You can have a try.

If you want to check it via T-SQL, then I don't know how you can do that.

Comment: On the properties page there is no link to the history (at least not in 2008 R2), you probably mean the context menu (when one right clicks the job)

Comment: There is a "View job history" link at the bottom of the properties window. I checked it on 2008 R2.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but I just had a similar situation where I needed to check on the status of jobs on SQL Server. A lot of people mentioned the sysjobactivity table and pointed to the MSDN documentation which is great. However, I'd also like to highlight the [Job Activity Monitor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187449(v=sql.105).aspx) which provides the status on all jobs that are defined on your server.

Answer (score 2):

Below script gets job status for every job on the server. It also tells how many steps are there and what is the currently running step and elasped time.

```sql
SELECT sj.Name,
    CASE
        WHEN sja.start_execution_date IS NULL THEN 'Never ran'
        WHEN sja.start_execution_date IS NOT NULL AND sja.stop_execution_date IS NULL THEN 'Running'
        WHEN sja.start_execution_date IS NOT NULL AND sja.stop_execution_date IS NOT NULL THEN 'Not running'
    END AS 'RunStatus',
    CASE WHEN sja.start_execution_date IS NOT NULL AND sja.stop_execution_date IS NULL then js.StepCount else null end As TotalNumberOfSteps,
    CASE WHEN sja.start_execution_date IS NOT NULL AND sja.stop_execution_date IS NULL then ISNULL(sja.last_executed_step_id+1,js.StepCount) else null end as currentlyExecutingStep,
    CASE WHEN sja.start_execution_date IS NOT NULL AND sja.stop_execution_date IS NULL then datediff(minute, sja.run_requested_date, getdate()) ELSE NULL end as ElapsedTime
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs sj
JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity sja
ON sj.job_id = sja.job_id
CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps as js WHERE js.job_id = sj.job_id) as js(StepCount)
WHERE session_id = (
    SELECT MAX(session_id) FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity)
ORDER BY RunStatus desc
```

Comment: very good, this works, shows the job that is running and the current step that is executing and for how long

Answer (score 1):

The tasks above work but I have seen many records in the msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity
**where run_Requested_date is not null 
and stop_execution_date is null** 
---- and the job is not currently running.

I would recommend running the following script to clear out all of the bogus entries (make sure no jobs are running at the time).

SQL2008:

```
    delete activity
    from msdb.dbo.sysjobs_view job  
    inner join msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity activity on job.job_id = activity.job_id 
    where  
        activity.run_Requested_date is not null  
    and activity.stop_execution_date is null
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into issues on one of my servers querying MSDB tables (aka code listed above) as one of my jobs would come up running, but it was not.  There is a system stored procedure that returns the execution status, but one cannot do a insert exec statement without an error.  Inside that is another system stored procedure that can be used with an insert exec statement.

```
INSERT INTO #Job
EXEC master.dbo.xp_sqlagent_enum_jobs 1,dbo
```

And the table to load it into:

```
CREATE TABLE #Job 
               (job_id               UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,  
               last_run_date         INT              NOT NULL,  
               last_run_time         INT              NOT NULL,  
               next_run_date         INT              NOT NULL,  
               next_run_time         INT              NOT NULL,  
               next_run_schedule_id  INT              NOT NULL,  
               requested_to_run      INT              NOT NULL, -- BOOL  
               request_source        INT              NOT NULL,  
               request_source_id     sysname          COLLATE database_default NULL,  
               running               INT              NOT NULL, -- BOOL  
               current_step          INT              NOT NULL,  
               current_retry_attempt INT              NOT NULL,  
               job_state             INT              NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way I found was to create a stored procedure. Enter the 'JobName' and hit go.

```
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Document Title: usp_getJobStatus

    Purpose:        Finds a Current Jobs Run Status     
    Input Example:  EXECUTE usp_getJobStatus 'MyJobName'

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    IF OBJECT_ID ( 'usp_getJobStatus','P' ) IS NOT NULL
    DROP PROCEDURE  usp_getJobStatus;

    GO

        CREATE PROCEDURE  usp_getJobStatus 
                          @JobName NVARCHAR (1000)

    AS

        IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#JobResults','U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #JobResults
        CREATE TABLE #JobResults ( Job_ID   UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL, 
                                   Last_Run_Date         INT NOT NULL, 
                                   Last_Run_Time         INT NOT NULL, 
                                   Next_Run_date         INT NOT NULL, 
                                   Next_Run_Time         INT NOT NULL, 
                                   Next_Run_Schedule_ID  INT NOT NULL, 
                                   Requested_to_Run      INT NOT NULL,
                                   Request_Source        INT NOT NULL, 
                                   Request_Source_id     SYSNAME 
                                   COLLATE Database_Default      NULL, 
                                   Running               INT NOT NULL,
                                   Current_Step          INT NOT NULL, 
                                   Current_Retry_Attempt INT NOT NULL, 
                                   Job_State             INT NOT NULL ) 

        INSERT  #JobResults 
        EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_sqlagent_enum_jobs 1, '';

        SELECT  job.name                                                AS [Job_Name], 
              ( SELECT  MAX(CAST( STUFF(STUFF(CAST(jh.run_date AS VARCHAR),7,0,'-'),5,0,'-') + ' ' + 
                        STUFF(STUFF(REPLACE(STR(jh.run_time,6,0),' ','0'),5,0,':'),3,0,':') AS DATETIME))
                FROM    msdb.dbo.sysjobs AS j 
                    INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory AS jh 
                       ON jh.job_id = j.job_id AND jh.step_id = 0 
                WHERE j.[name] LIKE '%' + @JobName + '%' 
                GROUP BY j.[name] )                                     AS [Last_Completed_DateTime], 
              ( SELECT  TOP 1 start_execution_date 
                FROM    msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity
                WHERE   job_id = r.job_id
                ORDER BY start_execution_date DESC )                    AS [Job_Start_DateTime],
            CASE 
                WHEN r.running = 0 THEN
                    CASE 
                        WHEN jobInfo.lASt_run_outcome = 0 THEN 'Failed'
                        WHEN jobInfo.lASt_run_outcome = 1 THEN 'Success'
                        WHEN jobInfo.lASt_run_outcome = 3 THEN 'Canceled'
                        ELSE 'Unknown'
                    END
                        WHEN r.job_state = 0 THEN 'Success'
                        WHEN r.job_state = 4 THEN 'Success'
                        WHEN r.job_state = 5 THEN 'Success'
                        WHEN r.job_state = 1 THEN 'In Progress'
                        WHEN r.job_state = 2 THEN 'In Progress'
                        WHEN r.job_state = 3 THEN 'In Progress'
                        WHEN r.job_state = 7 THEN 'In Progress'
                     ELSE 'Unknown' END                                 AS [Run_Status_Description]
        FROM    #JobResults AS r 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobservers AS jobInfo 
               ON r.job_id = jobInfo.job_id 
            INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs AS job 
               ON r.job_id = job.job_id 
        WHERE   job.[enabled] = 1
                AND job.name LIKE '%' + @JobName + '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH CTE_JobStatus
AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT NAME AS [JobName]
        ,s.step_id
        ,s.step_name
        ,CASE 
            WHEN [Enabled] = 1
                THEN 'Enabled'
            ELSE 'Disabled'
            END [JobStatus]
        ,CASE 
            WHEN SJH.run_status = 0
                THEN 'Failed'
            WHEN SJH.run_status = 1
                THEN 'Succeeded'
            WHEN SJH.run_status = 2
                THEN 'Retry'
            WHEN SJH.run_status = 3
                THEN 'Cancelled'
            WHEN SJH.run_status = 4
                THEN 'In Progress'
            ELSE 'Unknown'
            END [JobOutcome]
        ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), sjh.run_date) [RunDate]
        ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), STUFF(STUFF(CONVERT(TIMESTAMP, RIGHT('000000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), sjh.run_time), 6)), 3, 0, ':'), 6, 0, ':')) RunTime
        ,RANK() OVER (
            PARTITION BY s.step_name ORDER BY sjh.run_date DESC
                ,sjh.run_time DESC
            ) AS rn
        ,SJH.run_status
    FROM msdb..SYSJobs sj
    INNER JOIN msdb..SYSJobHistory sjh ON sj.job_id = sjh.job_id
    INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps s ON sjh.job_id = s.job_id
        AND sjh.step_id = s.step_id
    WHERE (sj.NAME LIKE 'JOB NAME')
        AND sjh.run_date = CONVERT(CHAR, getdate(), 112)
    )
SELECT *
FROM CTE_JobStatus
WHERE rn = 1
    AND run_status NOT IN (1,4)
```