# how to know status of currently running jobs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-agent

I need to know if a given Job is currently running on Ms SQL 2008 server. So as to not to invoke same job again that may lead to concurrency issues.

Comment: Job Activity Monitor in the SQL Server Agent section of SSMS.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

It looks like you can use `msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity`, checking for a record with a non-null start_execution_date and a null stop_execution_date, meaning the job was started, but has not yet completed.

This would give you currently running jobs:

```
SELECT sj.name
   , sja.*
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity AS sja
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs AS sj ON sja.job_id = sj.job_id
WHERE sja.start_execution_date IS NOT NULL
   AND sja.stop_execution_date IS NULL
```

Comment: This reports some non-running jobs on my servers.

Comment: I don't know enough about sysjobactivity. I just know I have a job that matches your where criteria for an activity several activties in the past. i.e. not the current or latest. The job is currently idle. I don't know if this represents a cancel, or an unplanned reboot etc. (SQL2008R2)

Comment: @Paul If you made your own question regarding this, there may be more information we could get about your problem, and potentially come up with a solutions - working things out in the comments isn't always easy.

Comment: I just felt when I saw something wrong with this answer I should say something, for future people not to take it absolutely at face. I've already had to move on from this subject for now.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/63349/oprhaned-entries-in-msdb-sysjobactivity

Comment: This includes jobs that have started but did not finish because they errored. `EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_help_job` works better

Comment: @Paul use `session_ID` to overcome the older session values.. using sysjobhistory you can check if job failed then we can avoid that results too.

Comment: @Paul: I believe the following StackOverflow answer might do the trick for you:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/18062236/216440  It only includes activity from the current SQL Agent session.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/13038752/216440 for an explanation of how activity records from previous sessions might be getting stuck.

Comment: Not the right answer, because this lists running jobs too.

Comment: I got a better answer here http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58859/script-to-see-running-jobs-in-sql-server-with-job-start-time, see answer by Kenneth Fisher which returns only currently running jobs

Comment: @AdamWenger My VM with SQL Server lost power while running a job. JobActivity has a NULL for stop_execution_date as a result, despite many other instance of the job completing successfully since that outage.

Answer (score 68):

I found a [better answer by Kenneth Fisher](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/64091).  The following query returns only currently running jobs:

```
SELECT
    ja.job_id,
    j.name AS job_name,
    ja.start_execution_date,      
    ISNULL(last_executed_step_id,0)+1 AS current_executed_step_id,
    Js.step_name
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity ja 
LEFT JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory jh ON ja.job_history_id = jh.instance_id
JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs j ON ja.job_id = j.job_id
JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps js
    ON ja.job_id = js.job_id
    AND ISNULL(ja.last_executed_step_id,0)+1 = js.step_id
WHERE
  ja.session_id = (
    SELECT TOP 1 session_id FROM msdb.dbo.syssessions ORDER BY agent_start_date DESC
  )
AND start_execution_date is not null
AND stop_execution_date is null;
```

You can get more information about a job by adding more columns from `msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity` table in select clause.

Comment: One important feature of this script is that it only selects jobs running in the current SQL Agent session.  Jobs that were running when a previous SQL Agent session ended will also have a NULL stop_execution_date.  We want to exclude those, hence the `ja.session_id = (SELECT TOP 1 session_id FROM msdb.dbo.syssessions ORDER BY agent_start_date DESC)`

Comment: Should probably leave this answer as a link to the original answer rather than copy the code because there's a useful comment highlighting a limitation: 'Unfortunately, this script assumes that the currently running step is the one after the last completed step. This isn't always the case'

Comment: how can I find errors that may have occurred while the job is running?

Comment: @GoldenLion, right-click on the job you ran and select job history. Then expand the failed job log. You can scroll down and see the reason for failure.

Answer (score 21):

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_help_job @Job_name = 'Your Job Name'
```

check field **execution_status**

0 - Returns only those jobs that are not idle or suspended.
1 - Executing.
2 - Waiting for thread.
3 - Between retries.
4 - Idle.
5 - Suspended.
7 - Performing completion actions.

If you need the result of execution, check the field **last_run_outcome**

0 = Failed
1 = Succeeded
3 = Canceled
5 = Unknown

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186722.aspx

Answer (score 17):

Given a job (I assume you know its name) you can use:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_help_job @Job_name = 'Your Job Name'
```

as suggested in [MSDN Job Help Procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186722%28SQL.90%29.aspx).
It returns a lot of informations about the job (owner, server, status and so on).

Answer (score 3):

This query will give you the exact output for current running jobs. This will also shows the duration of running job in minutes.

```
   WITH
    CTE_Sysession (AgentStartDate)
    AS 
    (
        SELECT MAX(AGENT_START_DATE) AS AgentStartDate FROM MSDB.DBO.SYSSESSIONS
    )   
SELECT sjob.name AS JobName
        ,CASE 
            WHEN SJOB.enabled = 1 THEN 'Enabled'
            WHEN sjob.enabled = 0 THEN 'Disabled'
            END AS JobEnabled
        ,sjob.description AS JobDescription
        ,CASE 
            WHEN ACT.start_execution_date IS NOT NULL AND ACT.stop_execution_date IS NULL  THEN 'Running'
            WHEN ACT.start_execution_date IS NOT NULL AND ACT.stop_execution_date IS NOT NULL AND HIST.run_status = 1 THEN 'Stopped'
            WHEN HIST.run_status = 0 THEN 'Failed'
            WHEN HIST.run_status = 3 THEN 'Canceled'
        END AS JobActivity
        ,DATEDIFF(MINUTE,act.start_execution_date, GETDATE()) DurationMin
        ,hist.run_date AS JobRunDate
        ,run_DURATION/10000 AS Hours
        ,(run_DURATION%10000)/100 AS Minutes 
        ,(run_DURATION%10000)%100 AS Seconds
        ,hist.run_time AS JobRunTime 
        ,hist.run_duration AS JobRunDuration
        ,act.start_execution_date AS JobStartDate
        ,act.last_executed_step_id AS JobLastExecutedStep
        ,act.last_executed_step_date AS JobExecutedStepDate
        ,act.stop_execution_date AS JobStopDate
        ,act.next_scheduled_run_date AS JobNextRunDate
        ,sjob.date_created AS JobCreated
        ,sjob.date_modified AS JobModified      
            FROM MSDB.DBO.syssessions AS SYS1
        INNER JOIN CTE_Sysession AS SYS2 ON SYS2.AgentStartDate = SYS1.agent_start_date
        JOIN  msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity act ON act.session_id = SYS1.session_id
        JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs sjob ON sjob.job_id = act.job_id
        LEFT JOIN  msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory hist ON hist.job_id = act.job_id AND hist.instance_id = act.job_history_id
        WHERE ACT.start_execution_date IS NOT NULL AND ACT.stop_execution_date IS NULL
        ORDER BY ACT.start_execution_date DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

```
EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_sqlagent_enum_jobs 1,''
```

Notice the column Running, obviously 1 means that it is currently running, and [Current Step].
This returns job_id to you, so you'll need to look these up, e.g.:

```
SELECT top 100 *
 FROM   msdb..sysjobs
 WHERE  job_id IN (0x9DAD1B38EB345D449EAFA5C5BFDC0E45, 0xC00A0A67D109B14897DD3DFD25A50B80, 0xC92C66C66E391345AE7E731BFA68C668)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @StepCount INT
SELECT @StepCount = COUNT(1)
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps
WHERE job_id = '0523333-5C24-1526-8391-AA84749345666' --JobID


SELECT
         [JobName]
        ,[JobStepID]
        ,[JobStepName]
        ,[JobStepStatus]
        ,[RunDateTime]
        ,[RunDuration]
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
                j.[name] AS [JobName]
            ,Jh.[step_id] AS [JobStepID]
            ,jh.[step_name] AS [JobStepName]
            ,CASE 
                WHEN jh.[run_status] = 0 THEN 'Failed'
                WHEN jh.[run_status] = 1 THEN 'Succeeded'
                WHEN jh.[run_status] = 2 THEN 'Retry (step only)'
                WHEN jh.[run_status] = 3 THEN 'Canceled'
                WHEN jh.[run_status] = 4 THEN 'In-progress message'
                WHEN jh.[run_status] = 5 THEN 'Unknown'
                ELSE 'N/A'
                END AS [JobStepStatus]
            ,msdb.dbo.agent_datetime(run_date, run_time) AS [RunDateTime]
            ,CAST(jh.[run_duration]/10000 AS VARCHAR)  + ':' + CAST(jh.[run_duration]/100%100 AS VARCHAR) + ':' + CAST(jh.[run_duration]%100 AS VARCHAR) AS [RunDuration]
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
            (
                PARTITION BY jh.[run_date]
                ORDER BY jh.[run_date] DESC, jh.[run_time] DESC
            ) AS [RowNumber]
        FROM 
            msdb.[dbo].[sysjobhistory] jh
            INNER JOIN msdb.[dbo].[sysjobs] j
                ON jh.[job_id] = j.[job_id]
        WHERE 
            j.[name] = 'ProcessCubes' --Job Name
            AND jh.[step_id] > 0
            AND CAST(RTRIM(run_date) AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) --Current Date
    ) A
    WHERE 
        [RowNumber] <= @StepCount
        AND [JobStepStatus] = 'Failed'
```

Answer (score 2):

We've found and have been using this code for a good solution. This code will start a job, and monitor it, killing the job automatically if it exceeds a time limit.

```
/****************************************************************
--This SQL will take a list of SQL Agent jobs (names must match),
--start them so they're all running together, and then
--monitor them, not quitting until all jobs have completed.
--
--In essence, it's an SQL "watchdog" loop to start and monitor SQL Agent Jobs
--
--Code from http://cc.davelozinski.com/code/sql-watchdog-loop-start-monitor-sql-agent-jobs
--
****************************************************************/
SET NOCOUNT ON 

-------- BEGIN ITEMS THAT NEED TO BE CONFIGURED --------

--The amount of time to wait before checking again 
--to see if the jobs are still running.
--Should be in hh:mm:ss format. 
DECLARE @WaitDelay VARCHAR(8) = '00:00:20'

--Job timeout. Eg, if the jobs are running longer than this, kill them.
DECLARE @TimeoutMinutes INT = 240

DECLARE @JobsToRunTable TABLE
(
    JobName NVARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    JobID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL,
    Running INT NULL
)

--Insert the names of the SQL jobs here. Last two values should always be NULL at this point.
--Names need to match exactly, so best to copy/paste from the SQL Server Agent job name.
INSERT INTO @JobsToRunTable (JobName, JobID, Running) VALUES ('NameOfFirstSQLAgentJobToRun',NULL,NULL)
INSERT INTO @JobsToRunTable (JobName, JobID, Running) VALUES ('NameOfSecondSQLAgentJobToRun',NULL,NULL)
INSERT INTO @JobsToRunTable (JobName, JobID, Running) VALUES ('NameOfXSQLAgentJobToRun',NULL,NULL)

-------- NOTHING FROM HERE DOWN SHOULD NEED TO BE CONFIGURED --------

DECLARE @ExecutionStatusTable TABLE
(
    JobID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY, -- Job ID which will be a guid
    LastRunDate INT, LastRunTime INT, -- Last run date and time
    NextRunDate INT, NextRunTime INT, -- Next run date and time
    NextRunScheduleID INT, -- an internal schedule id
    RequestedToRun INT, RequestSource INT, RequestSourceID VARCHAR(128),
    Running INT,    -- 0 or 1, 1 means the job is executing
    CurrentStep INT, -- which step is running
    CurrentRetryAttempt INT, -- retry attempt
    JobState INT -- 0 = Not idle or suspended, 1 = Executing, 2 = Waiting For Thread,
                     -- 3 = Between Retries, 4 = Idle, 5 = Suspended, 
                     -- 6 = WaitingForStepToFinish, 7 = PerformingCompletionActions
)

DECLARE @JobNameToRun NVARCHAR(128) = NULL
DECLARE @IsJobRunning BIT = 1
DECLARE @AreJobsRunning BIT = 1
DECLARE @job_owner sysname = SUSER_SNAME()
DECLARE @JobID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = null
DECLARE @StartDateTime DATETIME = GETDATE()
DECLARE @CurrentDateTime DATETIME = null
DECLARE @ExecutionStatus INT = 0
DECLARE @MaxTimeExceeded BIT = 0

--Loop through and start every job
DECLARE dbCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT JobName FROM @JobsToRunTable
OPEN dbCursor FETCH NEXT FROM dbCursor INTO @JobNameToRun
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    EXEC [msdb].[dbo].sp_start_job @JobNameToRun
    FETCH NEXT FROM dbCursor INTO @JobNameToRun
END
CLOSE dbCursor
DEALLOCATE dbCursor

print '*****************************************************************'
print 'Jobs started. ' + CAST(@StartDateTime as varchar)
print '*****************************************************************'

--Debug (if needed)
--SELECT * FROM @JobsToRunTable

WHILE 1=1 AND @AreJobsRunning = 1
BEGIN

    --This has to be first with the delay to make sure the jobs
    --have time to actually start up and are recognized as 'running'
    WAITFOR DELAY @WaitDelay 

    --Reset for each loop iteration
    SET @AreJobsRunning = 0

    --Get the currently executing jobs by our user name
    INSERT INTO @ExecutionStatusTable
    EXECUTE [master].[dbo].xp_sqlagent_enum_jobs 1, @job_owner

    --Debug (if needed)
    --SELECT 'ExecutionStatusTable', * FROM @ExecutionStatusTable

    --select every job to see if it's running
    DECLARE dbCursor CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT x.[Running], x.[JobID], sj.name 
        FROM @ExecutionStatusTable x 
        INNER JOIN [msdb].[dbo].sysjobs sj ON sj.job_id = x.JobID
        INNER JOIN @JobsToRunTable jtr on sj.name = jtr.JobName
    OPEN dbCursor FETCH NEXT FROM dbCursor INTO @IsJobRunning, @JobID, @JobNameToRun

    --Debug (if needed)
    --SELECT x.[Running], x.[JobID], sj.name 
    --  FROM @ExecutionStatusTable x 
    --  INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs sj ON sj.job_id = x.JobID
    --  INNER JOIN @JobsToRunTable jtr on sj.name = jtr.JobName

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        --bitwise operation to see if the loop should continue
        SET @AreJobsRunning = @AreJobsRunning | @IsJobRunning

        UPDATE @JobsToRunTable
        SET Running = @IsJobRunning, JobID = @JobID
        WHERE JobName = @JobNameToRun

        --Debug (if needed)
        --SELECT 'JobsToRun', * FROM @JobsToRunTable

        SET @CurrentDateTime=GETDATE()

        IF @IsJobRunning = 1
        BEGIN -- Job is running or finishing (not idle)

            IF DATEDIFF(mi, @StartDateTime, @CurrentDateTime) > @TimeoutMinutes
            BEGIN     
                print '*****************************************************************'
                print @JobNameToRun + ' exceeded timeout limit of ' + @TimeoutMinutes + ' minutes. Stopping.'
                --Stop the job
                EXEC [msdb].[dbo].sp_stop_job @job_name = @JobNameToRun
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                print @JobNameToRun + ' running for ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEDIFF(mi, @StartDateTime, @CurrentDateTime)) + ' minute(s).'
            END
        END

        IF @IsJobRunning = 0 
        BEGIN
            --Job isn't running
            print '*****************************************************************'
            print @JobNameToRun + ' completed or did not run. ' + CAST(@CurrentDateTime as VARCHAR)
        END

        FETCH NEXT FROM dbCursor INTO @IsJobRunning, @JobID, @JobNameToRun

    END -- WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    CLOSE dbCursor
    DEALLOCATE dbCursor

    --Clear out the table for the next loop iteration
    DELETE FROM @ExecutionStatusTable

    print '*****************************************************************'

END -- WHILE 1=1 AND @AreJobsRunning = 1

SET @CurrentDateTime = GETDATE()
print 'Finished at ' + CAST(@CurrentDateTime as varchar)
print CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEDIFF(mi, @StartDateTime, @CurrentDateTime)) + ' minutes total run time.'
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly for us with some minor adjustments.

Comment: Watch out for collation conflicts between "Latin1_General_CI_AI" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can query the table msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity to determine if the job is currently running.

Comment: this answer is incomplete or wrong. it doesn't say which column and information to look for in msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity. please update answer.