# How to know expected completion time of SQL Server SSIS job?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

My job is running since more than 24 hours.When I checked, what is actually going on using this ([how to know status of currently running jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18445825/how-to-know-status-of-currently-running-jobs)); its showing its still running. So is there any way to check, by what approximate time, this would complete? Is there any logic that has already implemented by Microsoft for this, like we have file transfer approximate time show?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to see an estimate of when a job will finish. The closest you can get is to put logging in that tells you when each task is started/completed (using the built in SSIS logging provider).

Logging to table or file, you can then check progress there and that will give you an indication how far through the job you are (and based off of your own knowledge of the package, you may be able to estimate how long until it will be finished)