# Schedule a job to run only if another job is not currently running in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-job

Currently have 2 jobs that can't run in parallel. Is there a way I can defer the execution based on the status? So MAG_LOGICAR_D3_H should not run if MAG_LOGICAR_D3_M is currently running and vice versa using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio ?

[image]

Comment: Either merge those two jobs in one, and treat them as two different steps, or maybe create flag somewhere in the database and set it to true when one of these jobs running, and on start always check for that flag.

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200195/how-can-i-determine-the-status-of-a-job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On way to accomplish this is using a maintenance plan.

1. Add two: `Execute SQL Server Agent Job Task`.
2. Configure the jobs.
3. Link both jobs.
4. Force the execution of second job after `Success` or `Completion` of the first one.