# Invoke-sqlcmd wait for Restoration to complete before going to next task

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm running this powershell script in order to restore a database on sql server.

> $Query = @" EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job N'Job'; GO "@
>
> Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance ....  -Query $Query -Verbose

I get this output => **VERBOSE: 'job' started successfully.**

When I check SQL server I find that the Database in restoring state but didn't finish.
My problem is that I need to make sure that the database was successfully restored before passing to the next tasks.

I made a deep research on how to do it using other methods, like using the dbo.restorehistory to get the result but it's not really efficient.

Is there a way to make Invoke-sqlCmd command wait for the job to finish before continuing the execution of the script?

Comment: Perhaps put the rest of the script in another job step, which will get executed only when this is finished. You can make a Powershell job step

Comment: Thank you for your proposition, it didn't solve the issue, I need to have Invoke-sqlcmd command passed only after the full completion of the restauration.

Comment: Have you considered using Invoke-SqlCmd to execute the restore database code directly, and thus synchronously, rather than firing off an asynchronous SQL Agent job?

Comment: Probably check the DM view for the restore command from `sys.dm_exec_requests` like https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2343/how-to-monitor-backup-and-restore-progress-in-sql-server/. Or you could try querying the job status?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18062236/7411885

Comment: Thank you for your propositions, I proposed to do the restauration directly but our team wants to keep the steps in sql server and only call the SQL agent jobs from the pipelines.
I found a way to make sure that the restauration was done successfully I'll post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to make sure that the restauration completed successfuly by using the stored procedure **sp_help_jobhistory** , here's the link for documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-help-jobhistory-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15.

Here's the script:

```
[string]$output;
$Query =@"
USE msdb;
GO

declare @temp table
(
    job_id varchar(255),
    job_name varchar(255),
    run_status varchar(255),
    run_date varchar(255),
    run_time varchar(255),
    run_duration varchar(255),
    operator_emailed varchar(255),
    operator_netsent varchar(255),
    operator_paged varchar(255),
    retries_attempted varchar(255),
    server varchar(255)
);
INSERT @temp  Exec dbo.sp_help_jobhistory @job_name = N'JobName';
select top 1 run_status from @temp order by run_date Desc, run_time ;

GO

"@
$output =  Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance xxxxxx -Database xxxxx  -Username xxx -Password  xxxx  -Query $Query  
$result = $output.itemArray
if ($result -eq '1'){
    Write-Host "Restauration succeded"
}
else { Write-Host "Restauration failed"}
```

I used a temporary table to read the content of the stored procedure, then I got the last job executed by ordering the result of the select query.

Also I added this script in a step before to test the restauration completion, because I can't access the database while it is in the restoration phase.

```
[string]$sucess = 'false'
$i = 0;
$ErrorActionPreference= 'silentlycontinue'
$query =@"
    SELECT * FROM tiers Where id = 1;
    GO
"@
do{
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance xxxxxx -Database xxxxx  -Username xxx -Password  xxxx  -Query $query   
    if($?){
        $sucess = 'true';
        break;
    }
    Write-Host "Echec"
    start-sleep -Seconds 60
    $i++
} While ($i -le 2 )
if ($sucess -eq 'true'){
Write-Host "Success"
}
Else { 
    Write-Host "Wait for too long, you need to manually check the restauration steps"
}
```

You can simply add the do...While in the first script, in my case I need to test the completion of restauration seperately from the script that checks the status of it.